# Is there a way to generate different instances of objects in python?

Tags: python, arcade

I'm making a game in python (using arcade library). I made a "Weapon" class, in which I could make different instances of weapons (with different sprites, damage stats, etc). And I want it so when a certain variable is True, the gun creates a new instance of a class (bullet), but I don't want to assign each instance to a new variable etc.
Is there a way to do this? And please do not make too complicated, because I haven't gotten too far in Python.

```py
class Weapon(object):
    def __init__(self, sprite, size):
        self.weapon = arcade.Sprite(sprite,size)
        self.attacking = True

    def draw(self):
        self.weapon.draw()
        if self.attacking:
            # Creates an instance of Bullet Class with initialized variables
            # Every single time this variable is turned into True
```

Comment: Objects don't need to be named to be created. Just store instances of them in a list or other type of container. You should cover lists sooner rather than later when learning Python.

Comment: You never need to assign an instance to a variable if you don't want to. You just need to put the instance *somewhere* for as long as it needs to live. Once no other object knows about your object, the garbage collector will destroy it. In your case, it sounds like you just want to make a list and add new objects into it. (You will also need to figure out when to *remove* objects from the list, but that depends on how long they're supposed to exist.)

Comment: I mean the bullets will also need to interact with another class (Zombies), should i just make a list to store the bullets, and then check to see of they make contact with another list that stores instances of Zombies? (Also should i just use a loop to generate the instances)

Comment: if you seek to run tasks in parallel then checkout the python threading module, if you need CPU power its multiprocessing . Can do asynctio in py 3.5>.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it like that, I would make a Sprite class containing the draw() logic, of which a Player and a Weapon class would inherit the player would contain the weapon and be instantiated in a Game class that will contain all your logic

```
class Sprite:
    def draw(self):
        # Draw logic, maybe have an image sprite member variable

class Bullet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, posX, posY, angle, velocity, game):
        self.posX = posX
        self.posY = posY
        self.angle = angle
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.game = game
        self.game.bullets.append(self)

    def fly(self):
         # Add some trigonometry here using the angle and velocity and implement some collision algorithm

class Weapon(Sprite):
    posX = 0
    posY = 0 #Probably gonna need to keep track of the position, you should init them in constructor
    angle = PI
    bullets = []

    def shoot(self):
        if len(self.bullets) <= 10: # maybe you don't want too many bullets
            self.bullets.append(Bullet(self.posX, self.posY, self.angle, 100))

class Player(Sprite):
    posX = 0
    posY = 0
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.weapon = Weapon()

    def shoot(self):
        self.weapon.shoot()

class Game:
    players = []
    bullets = []

    def __init__(self, player_count=1):
        for i in range(player_count):
            self.players.append(Player(self))

    def draw(self):
        for player in self.players:
            player.draw()
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.fly()


def main():
    game = Game(1)
    game.start() # need to implement start logic, rerendering every few MS, etc.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use setters for this

```
class Weapon(object):
    ...

    @property
    def attacking(self):
        return self._attacking

    @attacking.setter
    def attacking(self, value):
        if value and not self._attacking:
            # logic for when attacking become true
        self._attacking = value
```

Then when you do `somewep.attacking = True` on other parts of your code the setter will run. About saving the Bullet instances. If instantiating `Bullet` has all the side effects that it needs, then you don't need to save it, just `Bullet(parameters, ...)` and you'll be fine.

If the `Bullet` is being draw by the framework, then it has a reference to it and it shouldn't be collected by GC as long as the framework references it